# efficiently parsing 100 gb xml file

Tags: python, xml, algorithm, parsing

The file I have is a bit unstructured and messy.
I have foo.xml whose size is 100 gbs file such as:

```
<root>
    <abc>
         <page>
             <code>some_path_1</code>
             <string>another_path_1</string>
         </page>
    </abc>
    <def string="blah">
        <game>some_text_again</game>
        <blah attribs="yes" labs="check">some_text_again</blah>
    </def>
 .
 .
 .
 </root>
```

The expected output I need is:

```
some_path_1
another_path_1
attrib: string=blah
some_text_again
attrib: attribs=yes, labs=check
some_text_again
```

Currently I am using lxml parser. Such as:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse('foo.xml').getroot()
for i in root.iterchildren():
    # do something
```

What would be a better way to do it since it's a 100 gb file.

Comment: Since you're using `lxml`, you can use its incremental parsing feature. http://lxml.de/parsing.html#incremental-event-parsing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a huge file and found that I had to parse it incrementally.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
context = ET.iterparse(result_file_name, events=["end"])
    # turn it into an iterator
    context = iter(context)
    for event, elem in context:
        if event == "end":
        .....
```

Comment: This will still keep everything in memory, after iterating is finished the whole tree can be accessed as `context.root`. If you want to save memory, you need to `clear()` the elements after you're finished with them. The [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#incremental-event-parsing) has an example ("Modifying the tree").

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 3.0 with streaming enabled this would be:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"
     expand-text="yes" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  <xsl:template match="text()">{.}&xa;</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[@*]">attrib: {
     string-join(@* ! (name() || '=' || .), ', ')
  }&#xa;</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```